# API Paypal Payment Recurring

Tags: paypal

I have programmed a PaypalRequest Paypal where:

```
BILLINGPERIOD = Day
BILLINGFREQUENCY = 1
AMT = 10
TOTALBILLINGCYCLES = 3
```

Customer buys a reservation at a hotel, valued at USD 10.00, for 3 days

He will pay 10 USD each day until he completes 3 days.

How can I make it pay 3x 10 USD the same day?